# Visualizing the affine Bruhat decomposition for $\operatorname{SL}_2$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory, flag-varieties, bruhat-order

$
    \newcommand\Fl{\mathcal{F}\!\ell}
    \newcommand\numC{\mathbb{C}}
    \newcommand\numZ{\mathbb{Z}}
    \newcommand\ringO{\mathbb{O}}
    \newcommand\ringK{\mathbb{K}}
    \newcommand\power{\numC[\![t]\!]}
    \newcommand\laurent{\numC(\!(t)\!)}
    \newcommand\Wf{W\!_{f}}
    \DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}
    \DeclareMathOperator\Mat{Mat}
    \newcommand\aff{\mathbb{A}}
    \DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}
$Let $G$ be an algebraic group over $\numC$ with a Borel subgroup $B\subset G$, and let $I \subset G(\laurent)$ be the corresponding Iwahori subgroup, that is, $I$ is the preimage of $B$ under the evaluation map $G(\power) \to G(\numC)$, but regarded as a subgroup of $G(\laurent)$.
Consider the affine flag variety $\Fl = G(\laurent) / I $, acted on by $I$. It is written all over the literature that the orbits are parametrized by elements of the extended affine Weyl group $W = \Lambda \rtimes \Wf$, and that the closure of the orbit $\Fl_{\lambda}$ is given by $\overline{\Fl_{\lambda}} = \bigsqcup_{\mu\le\lambda} \Fl_{\mu}$.

I was trying to visualize this decomposition in the case of $G = \SL_2$.
Then clearly $I$ consists of matrices in $\SL_2(\power)$ which are upper triangular mod $t$.
The closure $\overline{\Fl_{e}} = \overline{I e I} / I = \bar{I} / I$
must be the image of the closure $\bar{I} \subset G(\laurent)$.
It is not clear to me what this closure is, as the description of $I$ is seemingly quite far from anything that can be easily described by polynomial equations in $\Mat_{2\times 2}(\laurent) = \aff_{\laurent}^{\!4} = \Spec( \laurent[ x_{ij} ] )$. I am also unsure about what the other orbits $ \Fl_{\mu} $ for $\mu\le \lambda$ are. The only reasonable action of $\Lambda = \numZ$ on matrices in $\SL_2(\laurent)$ I can think of is
$$
    \lambda \cdot x
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
        t^{\lambda}
            &
    \\
            & t^{-\lambda}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot x
    .
$$

What about the remaining $\Fl_{w}$ for $w \in \Wf$? Are those given by the same recipe as in the ordinary Bruhat decomposition where $BwB$ is well-defined because the action of $w \in \Wf = N(T) / T $ can be lifted to $N(T) \subset \SL_2$?

Comment: Why do you say that the closure of $\mathcal{Fl}_e$ is the image of the closure of $I$?  Rather, it seems to me that $\mathcal{Fl}_e$ is already a closed point.  (In fact, I think it's quite important to notice that—unless I am misunderstanding—you are changing ground fields when you take these quotients.  $G$ is a group over $\mathbb C((t))$, but $I$ is not an algebraic subgroup but rather a subgroup of the rational points, and, when you take the quotient, you now think of $G(\mathbb C((t)))/I$ as (I think) the $\mathbb C$-points of an ind-algebraic variety.)

Comment: Every element (well, both elements) of $W_f$ has a representative in $G(\mathbb C[[t]])$, so, yes, your representatives for $W$ can be taken in $N_{G(\mathbb C[[t]])}(T)\cdot T(\mathbb C((t)))$.  But I think I may have misunderstood what you're asking in that part of the question.

Comment: @LSpice Why would $\mathcal{F}\!\ell_e = IeI = I$ be closed? It is the set of matrices which are upper triangular mod $t$, i.e. the lower left entry belongs to $t \,\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!]$. I cannot think of any way to describe this by polynomial equations. The evaluation map $G(\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!]) \to G(\mathbb{C})$ does not look continuous to me, so why would the preimage of $B$ be closed? The statement that the closure of $I/I$ in $G( \mathbb{C} (\!( t )\!) )/I$ is the image of the closure of $I$ in $G( \mathbb{C} (\!( t )\!) )$ is, as far as I see, just a property of the quotient topology.

Comment: $\mathcal{Fl}_e$, in your notation, is not a subspace of $G(\mathbb C((t))$, but rather of $\mathcal{Fl} = G(\mathbb C[[t]])/I$, in which it is the closed point $I/I$.  I agree that $I$ itself is not closed in the subspace topology on $G(\mathbb C[[t]])$ coming from the Zariski topology (although it is closed in the analytic topology coming from the $t$-adic topology on $\mathbb C((t))$), but that's not the issue.  And then the point about fields of definition becomes, if you like, that $\mathcal{Fl}$ is not a topological quotient of $G(\mathbb C((t)))$ for the Zariski topology on the latter.

Comment: @LSpice It is in fact a subspace of $\mathcal{F}\!\ell = G( \mathbb{C} (\!( t )\!) )$ (but yes, my notation was a bit sloppy). If $\mathcal{F}\!\ell$ does not have the quotient topology, what topology does it have? Since the homogenous space $G/H$ of a group with respect to a closed subgroup is given the quotient topology (according to e.g. Humphreys, Linear Algebraic Groups), I had assumed that this was also the case here. But $I$ being non-closed, I guess the usual definition of the quotient does not immediately apply.

Comment: @LSpice Anyway, the fact that the formula $ \overline{ \mathcal{F}\! \ell _{\lambda} } = \bigsqcup_{\mu\le\lambda} \mathcal{F}\! \ell _{\mu} $ is written all over the literature (where my impression is that negative $\mu$ are included), that alone should prove that $\mathcal{F}\! \ell_{e} = I/I$ cannot be closed.

Comment: You can change your mind about notation, but in your post you put, as is usual, $\mathcal{Fl} = G(\mathbb C((t)))/I$.  I don't normally think about the topology on this (I'm interested in finite residue fields, where it's discrete), but I suspect it's given the quotient of the *analytic* topologies (with respect to which $I$ is a closed subgroup).  $e$ (I'm still having to assume you mean the identity) is minimal in the Bruhat ordering, so $\overline{\mathcal{Fl}_e} = \bigsqcup_{\mu \le e} \mathcal{Fl}_e$ also says $\mathcal{Fl}_e$ is closed.

Comment: @LSpice Damn, I don’t know how I managed to make a typo twice `xD` (probably because the expression `G( \mathbb{C} (\!( t )\!) )` was already quite convoluted, so I forgot the `/I` part), but you’re right. Here, $\mu\le e$ runs over $\mu$ in the *lattice* $\Lambda$, and I assume that negative elements are allowed. I think the negative ones are necessary in order to also get the negative powers of $t$. Humphreys writes explicitly that for a *closed* subgroup $H \subset G$, the homogenous space $G/H$ has the quotient topology. I don’t see a reason why this would not also be the case here.

Comment: And by quotient topology, I mean in the Zariski topology.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say.  If you have a specific reference in mind, then they give a topology.  If not, then you can define the topology to be whatever you want, but there's no guarantee it'll give the results you want.  To take a quotient by an algebraic subgroup, you need an algebraic subgroup, and, as you've observed, $I$ is not an algebraic subgroup—it's not even closed.  So we need some other candidate for a topology, and the analytic one seems natural to me, although, as I say, in my setting residue fields are finite, and so I never think about it.

Comment: $e$ is minimal (in fact least) in the entire affine Weyl group, including the translation lattice (I don't like the term 'negative', since lattices usually aren't totally ordered).  The order in $\mu \le \lambda$ is the Bruhat order, i.e., deletion of reflections in a reduced subexpression in terms of reflections.  The reduced word for the identity element is empty; you can't get anything Bruhat-beneath that, and it is Bruhat-beneath anything.